# Static method not being called

Tags: java

So I am working on a project that includes jsp, and I am setting attributes of a session. For some reason, it will not set attributes of a salesUserMap I am trying to create.

```
request.getSession(false).setAttribute("userMap", UserFactory.enumAllUsersForMap()); //this works
request.getSession(false).setAttribute("salesUserMap", UserFactory.enumSalesUsersForMap()); //this does not
```

I am basically doing the same code within this enumSalesUsersForMap() method as the other one, its just a little different SQL code. The problem is, I set breakpoints within that method, and they are not stopping. So it leads me to believe that the method is not even being called. No error messages either.

```
public static TreeMap<String, String> enumSalesUsersForMap() {
    Connection databaseConnection = null;
    TreeMap<String, String> salesUsers = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    PreparedStatement salesUserStatement = null;

    try
    {
        databaseConnection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        salesUserStatement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement("sqlcode here");
        ResultSet result = salesUserStatement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("enumsales");
        while(result.next())
        {
            salesUsers.put(result.getString("username"), result.getString("user_id"));
        }
        return salesUsers;
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("error reading users");
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
        databaseConnection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("error closing database");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you debugging?

Comment: using the eclipse debugger with breakpoints and I have watches as well. Tried defining a TreeMap and assigning it to the result of UserFactory.enumSalesUsersForMap(), but it did not get assigned anything.

Comment: I don't readily see why that method isn't getting called - can you put a debug statement as the first line of the method?

Comment: I tried doing a System.out.println("Im in enumSalesUsersForMap method"); Did not print. Really do not know why it is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to repackage it. I guess Tomcat was trying to pull everything from the old .class files that had been compiled already instead of everything within the workspace.